# Real functions with the property: $\ f(x_1)f(x_2) = f\left( \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \right)^2 $ for all $\ x_1,\ x_2\in\mathbb{R}.\ $

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, functional-equations

Suppose $\ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ $ has the property:$\ f(x_1)f(x_2) = f\left( \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \right)^2\ $ for all $\ x_1,\ x_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

I made some educated guesses and stumbled upon the fact that if $\ A,\alpha\in\mathbb{R},\ $ then $\ f(x) = A e^{\alpha x}\ $ satisfies this property.

I also realise that $\ f\ $ must be convex if $\ f>0\ $ and concave if $\ f<0$.

So now I'm wondering if *any other functions* satisfy the property, and if not, how to prove uniqueness of $\ f(x) = A e^{\alpha x}\ $ in satisfying the property. Edit: I want something stronger: to classify *all* the solutions to this functional equation.

Comment: Since $f(x_1)f(x_2=f(x_2)f(x_1)$ and $x_1+x_2=x_2+x_1$, the condition $x_1<x_2$ doesn't seem to mean much.  Is it just there to exclude $x_1=x_2$?  But all functions satisfy this if $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: And did you mean to assume continuity?  I would think there are discontinuous examples.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2370719/42969 (applied to $\log(f)$) shows that there are discontinuous examples.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers for nonintuitive results.

Comment: @lulu - I acknowledge your first point. @ Martin R I'm not sure what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: @kimchilover I am not familiar with Cauchy's functional equation. However, I don't see how this is related to it.

Comment: Suppose $g$ is a function that satisfies $g(x_1) + g(x_2) = 2g((x_1+x_2)/2)$. Then $f = A\exp(Bg)$ satisfies your equation for any constants $A,B$. If there was a non-continuous function that may serve as $g$, this would imply that $\{A\exp(Bx)\}$ is not the only class of functions that solves your equation. The references above tell you where to read about non-continuous solutions to the equation in $g$ - either in the answer Marin linked, or in stuff on the Cauchy equation, because any function that satisfies the latter can serve as $g$.

Comment: Note that $\,\frac{f(a)f(b)}{f(a+b)}/\frac{f(b)f(a-b)}{f(a)}=\frac{f(a)^2}{(f(a-b)f(a+b)}.$

Answer (score 2):

As stochasticboy commented while I was drafting this:

Let $\lambda(x)$ be any discontinuous solution of the additive form of Cauchy's functional equation.  One checks trivially that $\lambda(2u)=2\lambda(u)$ for all $u$, equivalently $\lambda(u/2)=\lambda(u)/2$.  Now let $f(x)=\exp(\lambda(x))$,
so
$$ f(x)f(y)=e^{\lambda(x)+\lambda(y)}=e^{\lambda(x+y)} =e^{2\lambda((x+y)/2)}=\left(f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\right)^2,$$
taking $u=x+y$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks; I wasn't.

Comment: Oh. I get this now. So the natural follow-up question: Are there any functions other than $exp$ of solution's to Cauchy's functional equation, that satisfy my inequality? The answer is yes, like $\ f(x) = Ae^{\alpha \lambda(x)},\ A\neq 1;\ \alpha\neq 1.\ $ I guess I want *all* the solutions to my original functional equation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ satisfies
$$ f ( x ) f ( y ) = f \left ( \frac { x + y } 2 \right ) ^ 2 \tag 0 \label 0 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $ iff there is a constant $ c \in \mathbb R $ and an [*additive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) $ A : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $ f ( x ) = c \exp \bigl ( A ( x ) \bigr ) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. The fact that those $ f $ that have this form are solutions is already discussed in the comments under the original post and the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4358509/229831) by [kimchi lover](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457779/kimchi-lover). To show that those are the only solutions, first note that if there is $ z \in \mathbb R $ with $ f ( z ) \ne 0 $, then letting $ y = 2 z - x $ in \eqref{0} we get $ f ( x ) f ( 2 z - x ) = f ( z ) ^ 2 > 0 $, and therefore $ f ( x ) \ne 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. This then shows that the right-hand side of \eqref{0} is always positive, which by looking at the left-hand side shows that $ f $ must be always positive or always negative. Let $ \epsilon = \operatorname {sgn} \bigl ( f ( 0 ) \bigr ) $, and note that $ \epsilon f ( x ) > 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, which lets us define $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ g ( x ) = \log \bigl ( \epsilon f ( x ) \bigr ) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Taking logarithms from both sides of \eqref{0}, we get
$$ g \left ( \frac { x + y } 2 \right ) = \frac { g ( x ) + g ( y ) } 2 \tag 1 \label 1 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $. \eqref{1} is known as *Jensen's functional equation*, and its solutions are exactly functions of the form $ g ( x ) = A ( x ) + b $ for some constant $ b \in \mathbb R $ and some $ A : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ satisfying [*Cauchy's functional equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). See "[Function that is both midpoint convex and concave: $f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850101/229831)" for a proof. Then we will have
$$ f ( x ) = \epsilon ^ 2 f ( x ) = \epsilon \exp \bigl ( g ( x ) \bigr ) = \epsilon \exp \bigl ( A ( x ) + b \bigr ) = c \exp \bigl ( A ( x ) \bigr ) $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, where $ c = \epsilon \exp b $. Note that we did all this with the assumption that there is some $ z \in \mathbb R $ with $ f ( z ) \ne 0 $, and ended up with some $ c \ne 0 $. In case there is no such $ z $, $ f $ must be the constant zero function, which is of the same form as before, only with $ c = 0 $.

Note that the axiom of choice implies the existence of nonlinear additive functions, which have wild behaviors. In case you have regularity conditions on $ f $ such as monotonicity, being bounded above/below on some interval, continuity and measurability, $ g $ and $ A $ will satisfy the same regularity condition, and we know that the only regular additive functions are linear ones. See "[Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/229831)" for more information.